# Gauge-equivalnt fields

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-fields

Suppose we have

$$V_1 = 0, \    A_1 = \frac{B}{2}(-y,x,0)$$

and

$$V_2 = 0,\   A_2=B(0,x,0)$$

I need to show that the potentials are equivalent and they represent the same magnetic and electric fields and find the gauge transformation that relates them.

So from what i know if we want to use gauge transformation:

$$v_2=v_1+\beta$$
$$A_2=A_1+\alpha$$

obviously then $\alpha = \nabla \lambda=\frac{B}{2}(y,0,0)$

But this whole thing just seems to easy. I also tried to compute the curl of the B field and integrate to get individual components but got something that didn't make any sense to. me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No, this is all you need to do: you've found a gauge transformation that connects the two, so they're gauge equivalent. You can also check that they produce the same electric and magnetic fields, but this just verifies what you already know.

Comment: Thats it? that seems too easy and doesn't agree with what i know about the professor:) lol